# How to use Google Drive without mounting

Tags: google-drive

I installed Google Drive and mounted it, but everytime I click it to open, it takes a bit of time to actually appear all the contents. Unlike Google Drive, Dropbox creates a normal folder called "Dropbox" in Home where I can easily access it to see what is inside, like any other normal holders. Is it possible to make the one for Google Drive so that I can easily access to Google Drive (this would be easier if I use command line to access it without mount)?

Comment: How did you install "Google Drive"? As far as I know, it is not available as a package for any Linux distro. I access it via my browser. Dropbox, on the other hand, is available for Ubuntu and other Linux distros.

Comment: I added it through "System Settings" => "Online Accounts".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Please see this article from March 2016: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-make-the-most-out-of-google-drive-on-gnome/. I don't know if things have improved since then.